# How would I solve this congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the best way to solve this congruence:

$r \cdot a^2  = b^3\bmod p$, where $p$ is prime

in general? $r$ and $p$ are known, and I want to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Fix a generator and rewrite the congruence using it; then it will be a linear problem.

Comment: Thanks! What does "fix a generator" mean?

Comment: The group of units is cyclic. Fixing just means picking one, i.e. "let $g$ be a generator" and then write $r,a,b$ as a power of $g$. Then you are effectively working on a linear equation in the additive group $\Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z$.